# R / ggplot2 / geom_density: how to use values in cells rather than number of entries

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first stack overflow post (hence can't post a pic). I've joined just to post this question as it's driving me mad. Up until now I have sufficed from previous questions, but have spent hours searching for a solution to this problem and (surprisingly, or unless I have missed something) have found nothing.

I'm sure this is an embarrassingly easy fix, but here goes.

Here is a simplified version of the data I am using:

```
Gender = c("F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M")

Year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016)

Total = c(820, 710, 420, 450, 360, 530)

data = as.data.frame(cbind(Gender, Year, Total))
```

All I want to do is create a density plot that shows the changing proportion of Male/Female totals over this 3 year tie period. This is the closest I have got:

```
ggplot(data, aes(as.numeric(Year), group=Gender, fill=Gender)) + 
  geom_density(position="fill")
```

However, what is happening is that ggplot is just displaying 2 equal sized rectangles, one on top of the other.

I assume this is happening as ggplot is reading the number of Gender entries, which is 3 + 3, so creating the equal bars.

The problem is that I can't get it to 'access' the values in the cells, when forming the M/F distribution for each year.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have already calculated the y value, you probably want `geom_area` not `geom_density`.

```
data = as.data.frame(cbind(Gender, as.numeric(Year), as.numeric(Total))) 

ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Total, fill = Gender)) + 
  geom_area(alpha = .6, position = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this (just tried up-voting, it said it's recorded but not displayed publicly as a new user).

Comment: One final thing though, I tried this with 'position = "fill"' to get something close to a solid filled-in density plot (would post a pic but not allowed), although it didn't quite work as the Total for each year was different (hence was slanted). Would I be best off manually calculating the M/F proportion per year and then re-doing the geom_area? Or is there a better way of incorporating proportion into geom_area?